# In-app purchase cause error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make in app purchase in my application but something is wrong. I made everything from this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html and from stackoverflows solutions but id didnt help and I'm still getting this error after run application:   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: queryInventory` caused by response `RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` It's happening after call method `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);` This is my code from onCreate in activity:

```
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, string1 + string2 + string3);
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            if (mHelper == null) return;
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
```

and variable definition in activity:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "**** TrivialDrive Error: " + "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        Purchase farmPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.SKU_FARM);
        isFarm = (farmPurchase != null);
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (isFarm ? "FARM" : "NOT FARM"));

        Purchase birdsPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.SKU_BIRDS);
        isBirds = (birdsPurchase != null);
        Log.d(TAG, "User " + (isBirds ? "BIRDS" : "NOT BIRDS"));

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

Do I missed something important?

Comment: Have you got the billing permission in manifest?

Comment: yes, and aidl file copied from this site https://github.com/congenialmobile/TrivialDrive

Comment: I used this tutorial and it worked for me: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: it didnt help, I'm still getting ` In-app Billing setup failed: IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)`

Comment: have got licence key from google developer console, and paste that licence key in the application

Comment: yes I have licence key included